# send data to server for req.params

Tags: node.js, express, routes

hello my current task is to send data to server and read from url with req.params but problem is that i am using ajax and can not set form action to send properly to specific url and it causes routing error i think problem is in form url  **/:token** but i dont know how to solve that problem. so i wish you understood, here is code:
( i have configuration for /forgot-password in index.js so i dont need to point it in url

FORM:

```
<form action="/forgot-password/reset/:token" method="POST" id="idform">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New password">
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(()=>{
    var $form = $('form#idform');

    $form.on('submit', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: $form.serialize(),

            error: (xhr,textStatus,error)=>{
                try{
                     const r = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                     if(r.message){
                         $('#err').html(r.message)
                     }
                }catch(error){
                    $('#err').html(xhr.responseText)
                }
            },
            success: (res)=>{
                window.location.replace(res.r)
            }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

NodeJS:

```
router.post('/reset/:token', (req,res)=>{
    async.waterfall([
        (done)=>{


            User.findOne({resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpirationDate: {$gt: Date.now()} }, (err,user)=>{
               if(err){
                   return res.status(500).send({message: err.message})
               }
               console.log(user)





                })
        }
    ])
})
```

thank you if you find a solution

Comment: have you tried changing your `router.post` to `router.post('/forgot-password/reset/:token' ...` ?

Comment: check out edit please

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that I understand the question exactly.  Can you post the exact error message you get?

Comment: i am not getting error message but user is undefined i mean that, that means ajax can not send data to url because url is invalid

Comment: i tried with validations and it worked for validations but not for user finding in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a templating engine (such as ejs) and pass the token as a variable. And use the correct path in your route

Comment: would that be safe?

Comment: i was thinking to do that and coz you told me i decided to do that and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this there is no need to place action here when you are sending data through ajax

```
<form method="POST" id="idform" data-token="your-token">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New password">
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Now in js**

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
  var $form = $('form#idform');

  $form.on('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/forgot-password/reset/'+ $('idform').data('token'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: $form.serialize(),

        error: (xhr,textStatus,error)=>{
            try{
                 const r = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                 if(r.message){
                     $('#err').html(r.message)
                 }
            }catch(error){
                $('#err').html(xhr.responseText)
            }
        },
        success: (res)=>{
            window.location.replace(res.r)
        }
    })
 })
})
```

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: i think you are adding :token directly inside data-token=":token" so its considering it as string and sending it inside req.params.token